# Query for finding not unique rows doesn't work properly in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010, having

With the code below, I'm trying to get not unique rows, rows which has a same pair of `columnName` and `TableName`. Table `columns_old` has about 22,000 values, query below returns 2000. I want to get such rows, because by trying to insert this `select` I get error rows with not unique values. This way I want to get such problematic rows:

```
SELECT  ColumnName,tablename                
                FROM columns_old

group by ColumnName, tablename
having count(*)> 1;
```

Result have been ordered by tableName, and I get such rows:

```
ColName       TableName

coa_end_dt      coa
coa_name        coa
coa_num         coa
coa_src_id      coa
coa_start_dt    coa
coa_template_id coa_tmplt
deleted_flag    geog_area
........         ......
```

But I thought that result be like this:

```
ColName       TableName

coa_end_dt      coa
coa_end_dt      coa
coa_name        coa
coa_name        coa
coa_name        coa
coa_num         coa
....
```

What is going on here? Just can't figure it out

Comment: Are you saying the results include pairs of ColName and TableName values which are found in only single rows ... not in multiple rows?  That doesn't seem possible.

Comment: So what exactly is wrong with this result?

Comment: Please put yourself in our shoes.  Without knowing what your data looks like, and what your desired output is, how can we tell that something is wrong with your output?  Based on your description of what you want, your query looks good.

Comment: "I'm trying to get not unique rows" - Can you try to explain yourself a little more?

Comment: Sorry but I still don't understand.  Can you show us a brief set of sample data and the output you want from a query based on that sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the revision to your question it seems you don't want to see only which combinations of *ColumnName* and *tablename* are present in more than one row.  You want to see the actual rows which contain them.

In that case, join your original query back to the source table to retrieve only the matching rows:

```sql
SELECT co.ColumnName, co.tablename
FROM
    columns_old AS co
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT ColumnName, tablename
        FROM columns_old
        GROUP BY ColumnName, tablename
        HAVING count(*)> 1
    ) AS sub
    ON co.ColumnName = sub.ColumnName AND co.tablename = sub.tablename;
```